# Play a stream with Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer?

Tags: windows-phone

In Windows Phone 8.1, I want to play an internet radio station with [Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer.aspx).  I'm aware of a sample which plays mp3 files with [MediaPlayer.SetUriSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer.seturisource.aspx).  However, I don't know how to play a stream.  I see [MediaPlayer.SetStreamSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer.setstreamsource.aspx), but it appears to be for random access streams which support seek, etc.  I'm not sure it's for live streams.

1. Which method should I use?
2. Any tutorials or docs on this? I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the Windows Phone Streaming Media library, which supports live streaming and HLS formats.

http://phonesm.codeplex.com/